# Estimate bias of a coin

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider a coin with probability $p$ of landing on head.  You can estimate the prob by tossing it lots of times and looking at the proportion of heads one gets.  In my problem I just want to know if $p<0.01$ and tossing coins is very expensive so I  want to do as few as possible.

To do this I will toss the coin and stop as soon as either I get a head or I have tossed it $100$ times.

How confident can I be that $p\geq 0.01$ if I stop because I get a head?

Answer (score 2):

**Revised per OP comments**

Your hypothesis test appears to be $H_0: p\leq 0.01$ vs. $H_a:p> 0.01$

There are two general outcomes:

1. You run out the test without getting a head. I.e., you get M tails (T), for some $M=$ max number of trials.
2. You get a head (H) on the $n^{th}$ toss $(X_n)$.

Under (1) $P(X_1=T,X_2=T...X_M=T|p> 0.01) \leq P(X_1=T,X_2=T...X_M=T|p=0.01) = 0.99^{M}$ Thus, you will not have much power to differentiate your hypotheses if you run out the test, but it is a result that is highly consistent with $p\leq 0.01$. Specifically, there is at least a $37\%$ chance of getting this result if $p\leq 0.01$, but *at most* a $37\%$ chance if $P>0.01$. Thus, you cannot reject $p\leq 0.01$, but the results are equivocal.

Under the more likely scenario (2), you will have stopped at some number $s\leq M$. We can bound the $p$-value as follows:

$p_s=\sum\limits_{i=1}^s P(X_1=T...X_{i-1}=T,X_i=H|p\leq0.01 ) \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^s(0.99)^{i-1}(0.01)\equiv\gamma_s$, thus your level of confidence that $p>0.01$ will be at least $1-\gamma_s$

Comment: That is interesting thank you. Say I am happy with a false rejection rate of 0.005 . Just to clarify however, in my experiment there are no variables. That is the stopping rule is fIxed so your comment about the sample size is confusing. I think I should ask a Bayesian version of this too as that seems interesting.

Comment: @Lembik I revised to make this more specific to specified test vs. the most powerful test.

Answer (score 1):

probability of tossing a head = p

Expected Number of trials = average number of trials till you get the first head

E = $p(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

S = $(1+2q+3q^2+4q^3+....)$

qS = $q+2q^2+3q^3+....)$

S-qS = $1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots$

S(1-q) = $\frac{1}{(1-q)}$

S = $\frac{1}{(1-q)^2}$

E =$\frac{p}{(1-q)^2}$

E = $\frac{1}{p}$

E = $\frac{1}{.01} = 100$

Expected number of trials you need to toss = $100$

Other way of looking at the problem is to find the minimum n

Probability that you will flip  a first head within n tosses = $p(1+q+q^2+q^3+....+ q^{n-1})$

$1-\alpha  = 1-q^{n}$

n = $\frac{log(\alpha)}{log(q)}$=$\frac{log(.38)}{log(.99)} = 97 times$

You can be $62\text{%} (1-\alpha)$ confident that if you flip the coin 97 times, the probability of the biased coin is going to be 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

If $p=\frac1{100}$, you do *not*  stop because of head with $(1-p)^{100}\approx \frac1e$, so even with $p$ slightly below $0.01$, you may stop because of head most of the time.

Comment: I was hoping to use the coin toss number to help the inference. So if I stop at toss 99 then I conclude that p is small but if I stop at toss 5 I conclude it isn't. Does that make sense? The 100 cut off is just for practical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Another method (@satish's) for computing the expected number of turns before a head.

Let $E(N)$ be the expected length of time $N$ for the first head to occur with probability p. Then I can write

$$
E(N) = p + (1-p)\left(1+E(N)\right),\tag{1}
$$

here I could get the head on the first go (the first term in Eq. (1)) or I could lose a turn getting a tails i.e. 1 in the second term, but then I start with the same expected number of heads i.e. E(N).

rearranging leads to

$$
pE(N) = 1\implies E(N) = \dfrac{1}{p}
$$